# Android check EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

i have a EditText which always contains an integer...but sometimes also contains the text..how do I check if my string contains text fields in the EditText?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: almost nothing, I can only check if the EditText is empty or not with this:                                                                                                      mDisplaySting = mDisplay.getText().toString();
           if(mDisplayString.length() != 0)

Comment: Do you want it to limit it to numbers _only_?

Comment: no .. filtering already did the same EditText.I solved with the answer of Raunak. Thanks for answer :D

Comment: Tony if you want to check if a string is null or empty try the utility method in TextUtils.isEmpty(String s);

Comment: No, I just wanted to know if the string contains only numbers or number+text. the check if a string is a null or empty i had already done. Grazie Simone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would approach the problem in the following manner:

```
String mEditText = mDisplay.getText().toString();
if(mEditText.matches("[0-9]+")) {
    // mEditText only contains numbers
} else {
    // mEditText contains number + text, or text only. 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can check if your text contains only numbers and/or letters.
If you build an utility method like this:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String s){
  if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s)){
    return false;
  }
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[-+]?[0-9]*");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
  return m.matches();
}
```

...then you can use it easily to check if your text retrieved from your TextView contains an integer or not :)

```
  String text = textview.getText().toString();
  if(TextUtils.isEmpty()){
    // We have got an empty string
  } else if(isNumeric(text){
    // Do something
  }else{
    // It's not numeric do something else
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `java.lang.Character.isDigit()`. You can check if a `String` is numeric by iterating over its characters and checking if they are digits.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can also register a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html on the EditText to do these operations as the field is changed. This allows you to do nice things like reject invalid characters as they are entered or turn the text red while it is invalid.

Comment: Also set the type on the EditText http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType